# Make Python import .pyc when run in optimized mode

Tags: python, import, compiler-optimization, pyc

I have to use some legacy .pyc modules (with no source) but I'm also forced to use python in optimized mode (`python -O`): so, when trying to import those modules, I get an import error (as python looks for .py or .pyo files).

Is there a way to make it use pyc modules as well? Or to convert .pyc into .pyo?

Comment: Does whoever forces you to use `-O` realize that the "optimizations" are pretty much stripping assertions and do nothing else?

Comment: I'm running Python under IIS through PyISAPIe and it runs in optimized mode (I've done no investigation on this)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to "convert" them is simply renaming them.  Of course they won't be optimised, but at least you can use them.

Comment: Specifically, assertions won't be stripped. But that won't make much of a difference... or at least it shouldn't. There's a surprising amount programmers that use `assert` for input validation.

Comment: It worked, thanks. This make me wonder why couldn't python import them by itself

Answer (score 2):

You can use [DePython](http://depython.com) to convert your .pyc files into .py files, and then you will be able to import them.